# Importance of the caching [Spark]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching

Could you explain me please why does the following happen?

I have a .csv file with some data (about 25kk rows).
I'm doing the following:

```
val RDD1 = sc.textFile(...).map(...).aggregateByKey(...).
           mapValues(...).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Then I'm doing with RDD1 some more transformations:

```
val RDD2 = RDD1.zipWithIndex(...).cartesian(...).filter(...).map(...)
```

At this moment there are about 14kk elements in RDD2 and for each of them I'm doing some calculations.
Finally I'm writing the result into files:

```
RDD2.map(...).saveAsTextFile(...)
```

It seems to be working. But if I don't use the persist() method, then I'll get some different errors such as GC error, heartbeat timeout errors as so on.
I thought that caching is essential only if I use the RDD1 many times, so I don't have to evaluate it for the second time. But I'm using RDD1 only one time - to create RDD2. Why is it happening?

Thank you in advance!

PS: I'm attaching [my code](https://pastebin.com/TSdBuMC1) there just if what I described above is not enough to detect the problem.

Comment: Isn't that just a sign that your installation is unstable and that errors do in fact occur when re-computation is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I thought that caching is essential only if I use the RDD1 many times, so I don't have to evaluate it for the second time*

It is recommended to use `persist` or `cache` anytime we want to reuse an RDD (no matter how many times).

In the example used on your question:

```
val RDD2 = RDD1.zipWithIndex(...).cartesian(...).filter(...).map(...)
```

when transformations are called on `RDD1`, `RDD1` is reevaluated.

From the docs:

> Spark also automatically persists some intermediate data in shuffle operations (e.g. reduceByKey), even without users calling persist. This is done to avoid recomputing the entire input if a node fails during the shuffle. **We still recommend users call persist on the resulting RDD if they plan to reuse it.**

Comment: I'm not sure I got you right. Could you rephrase it, please?

Comment: Thank you, I think I finally got it.